# Computing the correlation / covariance of time series of multiple length and multiple variables

Tags: time-series, python, time-varying-covariate, scipy

I have N time series of DIFFERENT lengths with i number of data points in each observation.

I would like to compute the similarity of each time series and generate M number of clusters.

I have tried Jaquard simliarity,  and followed the link below

[Time Series Similarity : Differing Lengths with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58725/time-series-similarity-differing-lengths-with-r)

but am looking for a similar solution in Python here
(which I have found https://github.com/slaypni/fastdtw)

The other problem is the NUMBER of features in the dataset (it is not just X & Y). X  = Time, but I have 5 vectors for Y.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

from fastdtw import fastdtw
x = x
y = y
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
distance, path = fastdtw(x, y, dist=euclidean)
print(distance)
```

Works fine for uneven dimension size, but if I add multiple dimensions it kicks out an error. Should I do some transposing?

Finally, if I can calculate the distance between each pair, what is the best way to cluster them?